# Extending Primary Linux Partition on Hetzner Cloud Volumes

Tags: filesystems, partition, gparted

I have Hetzner cloud server with 20GB /sda & additional volume of 30GB /sdb
How can I extend /sda ?

[image]

Comment: Please [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397)

Answer (score 0):

If the volume is actually extendable then you could use the following commands, given you use ext4 in the last line.

```
#scan for disk-changes if those happened in a vm-environment by $host
echo 1 > /sys/block/sda/device/rescan
#install cloud-guest-utils which provide `growpart`
yum install cloud-utils-growpart
#extend partition to maximum available size
growpart /dev/sda 1
#extend ext4?
resize2fs /dev/sda1
```